# SharePoint version column

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, versioning

Is there any way to store previous value of column in SharePoint 2010 in another column .

I'd like to show the old version of column A in column B and if it can be done without SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to make some kind of *On Item Update* functionality, whether it be a workflow (can be created via SharePoints userinterface) or an eventreceiver (custom code bound to lists via feature activation or console job) to get the current value of **A** and insert it into **B**.

Comment: Great, can you tell me how can this be done using workflow ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid, the only way to do it - is to make you own control to display list of items with this field or may be make your own custom field.

Comment: ok thanks for your reply, how can i create a custom field for that